# ps -ef | wc -l adds tab to the front of the line

Tags: bash, ps, wc

I'm trying to store the output from a ps and later compare it.
I'm using the following line:

```
siteminder_running=`ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep LLAWP | wc -l`
```

When I tried to compare the output I found that the variable has a tab in front of the number.

This is the output:

```
-       0- value
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but you can probably circumvent it by eliminating `wc`: you can replace `grep LLAWP | wc -l` with `grep -c LLAWP`.

Comment: This is the output of what? Please update your question to show the exact command that produces that output.

Answer (score 3):

Like ruakh pointed out you can just use `grep -c`

```
siteminder_running=`ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep -c LLAWP`
```

For fixing white space in general, I use `xargs echo` like this:

```
siteminder_running=`ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep LLAWP | wc -l | xargs echo`
```

Answer (score 1):

The wc(1) utility provided with most Unix and GNU/Linux releases prints to user terminal input filename and count (of lines/characters/what you asked it to print) separated by TAB.

In case of standard input, there is no input filename, resulting just a TAB in front of count.

There are several ways to circumvent this, for example:

```
ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep LLAWP | wc -l | awk '{ printf "%d\n", $0 }'
printf $(ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep LLAWP | wc -l)
ps -ef | grep $iplanet_home | grep LLAWP | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

As said, these are just examples, there are literally dozens ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: and as ruakh as pointed out in his comment above, the most efficient way is `...| grep -c LLAWP`. Good luck to all.

Comment: It is useful to know *why* the tab is there in the first place.